# SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have Subscribers table in the DB which cantains DateCreate field that has default value GetDate().
When I try to add new record to the table via Entity Framework:

```
        Subscribers subs = new Subscribers();
        subs.Email = email;
        subs.DateCreate = DateTime.Now;
        DataBase.DBContext.AddToSubscribers(subs);
        DataBase.DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

it throws an exception:
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: is that the only `Date` property in your transaction? the code seems fine

Comment: What are the other fields defined in the Subscribers class? If any are DateTime, are they nullable?

Comment: Yes, there is another nullable DateTime field there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure your machine clock is not in 15th century ;-)
2. Recreate your model.
3. It your table has default value you don't have to set it in code.
4. Consider using `GETUTCDATE()` instead of `GETDATE()`
5. Make sure there are no other DateTime fields without default values.

Comment: Yes, there is another nullable DateTime field there and what?

Comment: Make sure that your property is of type `DateTime?` not `DateTime`. In latter case `DateTime.MinValue` will be inserted into table, causing the exception. `MinValue` is way before 1753...

Comment: Hm, how can I do that if model was generated automatically ?

Comment: If the other property is not `DateTime?` than your column may not be NULL-able. Verify it. Also, you might want to post your table schema and generated entity.

Comment: Yes, other property is DateTime also because I even can't set up DateTime? type for any property. DateCreate isn't nullable... Isn't stupid framework?

Comment: No, the framework isn't stupid. In your EDMX diagram set `Nullable` to `True` for the other property, or delete the table and update model from database (assuming your database has nullable field).

Comment: But other field is nullable. it has Nullable=True. I updated model from DB, but same problem

Comment: Can't help more without source code... And nullable datetime fields do work with EF.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, but I had the same problem just now. The reason for this problem is that you have another date in your entity, and the default (MinValue) for that will be 1/1/0001. In SQL/Server, the default (MinValue) is 1/1/1753 or something.

I found a great article that helped me out at [vfstech.com](http://vfstech.com/?p=111), which suggests using datetime2 instead of datetime in the database, however this wasn't an option for me. However it also has code that does the translation both ways. I quickly created a class that inherited from my entity class and used that in my application and it solved my problem just fine without me having to infect my business logic with something that in my view, Microsoft should have implemented properly to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Convert.ToDateTime()` in .Net code then please check the application hosted server's calendar setting, mainly the time zone and short date format